# SELECT query failing after updating it

Tags: php, sql

I modified the following query and am now getting this error.

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given

I have read into what this error means and I know it is my query that is wrong. This worked perfectly before I changed the query. It was this before...

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");
```

I changed it to...

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3, 4 ,5");

$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

What am I doing wrong in the new query?

Comment: It looks like the variable `$query` is a boolean rather than a mysqli_result object. This probably means that the `mysqli_query()` function is failing and thus `$query` is getting set to `false`. Turn on error reporting in PHP if you haven't already, and see what's failing with the MySQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comma separated value use IN

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` IN(3,4,5);
```

Comment: For some reason, after updating this, the output still only shows the group 3 users?

Comment: Check value present in database for 4 and 5 group.

Comment: They are in the database.

Comment: Okk try with remove space before 4 and 5!!

Comment: I think the error might have to do with JS that I have below it. The query is outputting all of the correct names. JS just isn't grabbing them. Not sure why. Thanks though1

Answer (score 1):

your query has a mistake.

Try this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` in (3, 4 ,5)");
```

The `in` serves the same function as an `OR`

Comment: For some reason, after updating this, the output still only shows the group 3 users?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is indeed wrong, you cannot check a value like that.
If you want to check against multiple values, you can make use of the [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) keyword.

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` IN (3, 4 ,5)"
```

Comment: For some reason, after updating this, the output still only shows the group 3 users?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check of either one of the choice use `IN` instead:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` IN (3, 4 ,5)");
```

Comment: For some reason, after updating this, the output still only shows the group 3 users?

Comment: that's odd.  Try a query to check for 4 alone, like your original attempt with 3  and report your results

Comment: @Becky try to look for the other values?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this following also,may be you will get your result.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE group = 3 or group = 4 or group = 5;
```

Thanks.

Comment: With the AND operator you won't get any results here. You cannot have a value that is 3 AND 4 at the same time. And do not forget to backtick your column names (and table name, but that is less essential here).